# How to check publishing page state-Approved/Rejected

Tags: sharepoint-online, publishing-page, approval-process

Is there any way to check if publishing page in sharepoint online is approved/Rejected? Would be great if I can add JS in custom page layout to have check on this.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out using REST API. If someone else need it ,can use following code snippet.

[image]